# Changing properties in Seaborn displot

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, normal-distribution

It looks like a pretty straightforward task but I cannot find the right solution.
I do generate 10 collections with 100 samples in each and pack them into **pandas.DataFrame** assigning index numbers for each column.

How to plot all 10 lines with: same color='b' for all, set alpha=0.5, linewidth=1.0 ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import random


sns.set_style("darkgrid")
sns.set_context("talk")
SEED = 202107
np.random.seed(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)


Num = 10
val = [np.random.randn() for _ in range(Num)]
my_data = [mu + np.random.randn(100) for mu in val]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for index in range(Num):
    name = str(index)
    df[name] = my_data[index][:]

sns.displot(df, kind='kde', legend=False)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer requires realizing that in [wide-form mode](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html), `displot` assigns the column dimension to a `hue` variable. So you control the color through the `palette` parameter and the easiest way to make everything one color is to pass a list of identical entries with the right length. The other properties can be controlled by matplotlib keyword arguments that get passed through to `plt.plot`:

```py
g = sns.displot(
    df, kind='kde', legend=False,
    palette=["C0"] * Num, linewidth=1
)
plt.setp(g.ax.lines, alpha=.5)
```

[image]

It looks like there's a bug where `alpha=` is ignored, which you can workaround by modifying the artists after plotting (as above) or by defining the palette as `[mpl.colors.to_rgba("C0", alpha=.5)] * Num`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It does a good job. alpha property makes no effect.